# No definition of _SC_CLK_TCK

Tags: linux

I'm working with a embedded Linux 2.6.36

I need that sequence:

```
ticksPerSecond=sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK); // ticks per sec
```

But I got this error

```
semLib.c:96: error: '_SC_CLK_TCK' undeclared (first use in this function)
semLib.c:96: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
semLib.c:96: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

I didn't find a define of

> _SC_CLK_TCK

I found out that it should be in linux/time.h. But it isn't.

Answer (score 6):

Try `#include <unistd.h>`. It includes the header with this and other definitions.

Comment: Looks like your toolchain is a little less standard than it usually is. Does `fgrep -rn SC_CLK_TCK /usr/include` finds the symbol? (Replace /usr/include with your toolchains directory with headers)

Answer (score 0):

On my debian 6, with the same issue

```
xxx.c:47: error: '_SC_CLK_TCK' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I found this :

```
/usr/include/bits/time.h:41:#   define CLK_TCK ((__clock_t) __sysconf (2))      /* 2 is _SC_CLK_TCK */
```

Which says you can use (2) instead :)
For me it returns 100 ticks per second (only !)